# Difficult to understand what exactly .has does with array in joi

Tags: node.js, joi

I was trying to learn JOI to validate a schema,I came across the following content

```
const schema = Joi.array().items(
  Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.number()
  })
).has(Joi.object({ a: Joi.string().valid('a'), b: Joi.number() }))
```

And I validated the scheme as follow `let c = arr2.validate([{ a:'a', b:'b'}])` the response I got on validation is

```
{
  value: [ { a: 'a', b: 'b' } ],
  error: [Error [ValidationError]: "[0].b" must be a number] {
    _original: [ [Object] ],
    details: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

then I tried the above validation with the schema as follows

```
const arr2 = Joi.array().items(
  Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.number()
  })
)
```

even now I got the following validation response

```
{
  value: [ { a: 'a', b: 'b' } ],
  error: [Error [ValidationError]: "[0].b" must be a number] {
    _original: [ [Object] ],
    details: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

I'm just confused as to whats the use of .has in the first schema as I can have the valid value directly as below

```
const arr2 = Joi.array().items(
  Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string().valid('a'),
    b: Joi.number()
  })
)
```

then what exact purpose is .has serving in the first schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [`.has()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#arrayhasschema) documentation:

> Verifies that a schema validates **at least one of** the values in the array

The example schema...

```
const schema = Joi.array().items(
  Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.number()
  })
).has(Joi.object({ a: Joi.string().valid('a'), b: Joi.number() }))
```

...requires **at least one of** the array items to pass the validation `{ a: Joi.string().valid('a'), b: Joi.number() }`

e.g.

```
{ "a": "a", "b": 12345 }
```

Your schema on the other hand...

```
const arr2 = Joi.array().items(
  Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string().valid('a'),
    b: Joi.number()
  })
)
```

...will **only** accept items that pass the validation `{ a: Joi.string().valid('a'), b: Joi.number() }`.

The first schema will still accept something like...

```
[
    {
        "a": "foo",
        "b": 12
    },
    {
        "a": "a",
        "b": 99
    },
    {
        "a": "bar",
        "b": 6
    }
]
```

...where yours will not because not all `a` keys have the value `'a'`.